# LWC + Jest: Assert about what happens before a wire adapter returns data

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-jest

I have a LWC with a wired function hooked up to the `getFiles` method in an Apex class, like this:

**myLwc.html**

```html
<template>
    <template if:true={showSpinner}>
        <lightning-spinner
            alternative-text="Loading"
            size="medium"
        ></lightning-spinner>
    </template>
    ...
</template>
```

**myLwc.js**

```js
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from "lwc";
import getFiles from "@salesforce/apex/MyApexController.getFiles";

export default class MyLwc extends LightningElement {
    @track files;
    showSpinner = true;

    @wire(getFiles, { recordId: "$recordId" })
    loadFiles({ data, error }) {
        if (data) {
            this.files = data;
        } else if (error) {
            // ...
        }
        console.log("setting showSpinner to false");
        this.showSpinner = false;
    }
}
```

I want to write a test that asserts that the spinner appears in the DOM until the wired function gets its return value or errors.  I'm trying to do it like this:

**myLwc.test.js**

```js
import { createElement } from "lwc";
import { registerApexTestWireAdapter } from "@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest";
import myLwc from "c/myLwc";
import { getRecord } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";

// Set up wired data mocking
const mockGetFiles = require("./data/getFiles.json");
const getFilesWireAdapter = registerApexTestWireAdapter(getFiles);

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
const flushPromises = () => new Promise(setImmediate);

describe("crmOppFiles tests", () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it("shows the spinner until files are loaded", async () => {
        console.log("starting test");
        const element = createElement("c-my-lwc", { is: myLwc });
        element.recordId = "OPP001";

        // Add the component to the DOM
        document.body.appendChild(element);
        console.log("after appendChild");

        // The spinner should be present initially
        const spinner = element.shadowRoot.querySelector("lightning-spinner");
        expect(spinner).toBeTruthy(); // IT FAILS HERE

        // Simulate the getRecord wire service returning data
        getFilesWireAdapter.emit(mockGetFiles);

        // Wait for all async processes to complete
        await flushPromises();

        // Now that all initial data retrieval is complete, the spinner should
        // be hidden
        expect(spinner).toBeFalsy();
    });
});
```

My console output shows up in the following order...

```
starting test
setting showSpinner to false
after appendChild
```

... which tells me the LWC framework doesn't actually wait until you call `getRecordWireAdapter.emit()` to execute the wired function.

That being the case, is there any way to test for conditions that are present before the wire service returns a response (like spinners, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On closer inspection, I found out that the `@wire`-decorated function gets called immediately when the component loads, before there is an actual response.  `data` and `error` are both undefined in that call.  So my assumption that the function only got called based on a true data/error response was misplaced.

Rewriting my LWC like this, now the test passes:

```
@wire(getFiles, { recordId: "$recordId" })
loadFiles({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.files = data;
    } else if (error) {
        // ...
    }
    if (data || error) {
        this.showSpinner = false;
    }
}
```